# Sorting array in an ascending array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

When I try to sort the array, the result that I get is:

```
The sorted array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The user fills the array with `8` numbers that should be eventually sorted. But what I'm getting is a bunch of `0`s.
Why am I getting `0s`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortArray {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number for index " + i);
            int number = kbd.nextInt();
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[j]) 
                {
                    int temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("The sorted array is " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }

}
```

Comment: number is an array.use number[i] instead of number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning the user inputs to your array, which is why all the elements remain 0.

change

```
int number = kbd.nextInt();
```

to

```
numbers[i] = kbd.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is within these lines of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number for index " + i);
            int number = kbd.nextInt();
        }
```

Specifically `int number = kbd.nextInt();`

**To add a little bit of explanation to Eran's answer**, what you did in that line above is create a new variable number, and assign the value you get from the Scanner kbd. As you declare an `int` (meaning you write `int` on the left hand side) you're ***creating* a variable** that will hold an `int` value.

The main issue here is that right after you assign it to a variable called `number`, your loop closes and the variable is not used at all. It gets destroyed/removed/garbage-collected and the value is released. Next time you come around that loop again, a new variable called number is once again assigned with that value from the scanner.

Also notice now `number` and `numbers` are of different types, numbers is an array of ints, while number is just an int.

By changing `int number` to `numbers[i]`, you're telling Java to assign the int received from the scanner `kbd` to the array `numbers` at position `i`. That way you don't lose the value and it gets saved inside the array, which is why when you print the array you no longer get all 0s. (the reason why you previously got all zeros is because you **initialized an array of `ints`, but never given them values, so Java defaults to 0**.